# Node's epoll behaviour on socket

Tags: node.js, kernel, node-modules, v8

I wrote a simple node.js program that sends out 1000 http requests and it records when these requests comes back and just increases counter by 1 upon response. Endpoint is very light weight and it just has simple http resonse without any heavy html. I recorded that it returns me around 200-300 requests per second for 3 seconds. On other hand, when i start this same process 3 times (4 total processes = amount of my available cores) i notice that it performs x4 faster. So i receive aproximately 300 * 4 requests per second back. I want to understand what happens when epoll gets triggered upon Kernel notifying the poll about new file descriptor being ready to compute (new tcp payload arrived). Does v8 take out this filedescriptor and read the data / manipulate with it and where is the actuall bottleneck? Is it in computing and unpacking the payload? It seems that only 1 core is working on sending/receiving these requests for this 1 process and when i start multiple (on amount of my cores), it performs faster.

Answer (score 0):

> where is the actuall bottleneck?

Sounds like you're interested in profiling your application. See https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/ for the official documentation on that.

What I can say up front is that V8 does not deal with file descriptors or `epoll`, that's all Node territory. I don't know Node's internals myself (only V8), but I do know that the code is on https://github.com/nodejs/node, so you can look up how any given feature is implemented.